# Project started in Xcode 4.3 compiled in Xcode 5 defaulting to iOS 6 Navigation Bar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode4.3, xcode5

I'm having a weird and intermittent issue where my UINavigationBar is showing iOS 6 style. The app was originally created in Xcode 4.3 but I can't seem to pin down what makes it use the old style. Is there any definitive way to ensure that this is taken care of?

Answer (score 0):

In your target build settings make sure you use the latest SDK (7.0) as base sdk.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that. :(
https://www.dropbox.com/s/plid7x5dxgeol4a/Screenshot%202013-10-30%2010.02.04.png